# The image changes automatically - Start button

Tags: javascript, css, image

I wanted to add a button to start the change between images, to avoid the start of the change on its own

You must press the button until the change starts

```js
      var imageSources = ["https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg", "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg"]

      var index = 0;
      setInterval(function(){
        if (index === imageSources.length) {
          index = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("image").src = imageSources[index];
        index++;
      }, 2000);
```

```html
 <img id="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" style="width:300px">
```

Comment: whats you question??

Comment: I didn't see any button in your HTML.

Comment: I wanted to add a button to start the change between images, to avoid the start of the change on its own

Comment: Then you should add a button in HTML and handle it's on click event. Inside on click event function, you should put your image change code. Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please have a look I hope it's helpful Thanks
https://jsfiddle.net/sanat/xc5w8ngy/7/

```
<button id="start">
start
</button>
<button id="stop">
stop
</button>
<br>
<br>

<img id="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" style="width:300px">



var myVar = '';
    $(function(){
        $("#start").on('click',function(){
       var imageSources = ["https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg", "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg"]


      var index = 0;
     myVar = setInterval(function(){
        if (index === imageSources.length) {
          index = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("image").src = imageSources[index];
        index++;
      }, 2000);

      });

      $("#stop").on('click',function(){
         clearInterval(myVar);
      });

    });
```